# How to perform ctrl+j in ruby for chrome browser. I am using RubyMine and WatirWebdriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, browser-automation

Tried below code to click ctrl+J but did not work for chrome browser.
@browser.driver.action.key_down(:control).send_keys("j").key_up(:control).perform
Also tried
@browser.driver.action.send_keys(:control,"J").perform

I read in one blog, above code would work for Firefox browser but not for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

First off,

The way you send `control+j` is wrong. The way to send the `control+j` is,you have to give control+k inside the `[]` like `[:control,"j]`

```
b.send_keys([:control,"j"])
```

Second off,

it's not possible to send the `[:control,"j]` via chromedriver because of the following issue

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=903

The exact answer lies here

```
This is a limitation in the way we simulate keyboard input in ChromeDriver. Keys get sent directly to the render process, bypassing the browser process. So any keyboard shortcut handlers in the browser process will not be invoked by sendKeys().
```

Comment: To point @srikanth in the right direction how browser downloads *should* be handled: http://watir.com/guides/downloads/

Comment: @GijsPaulides Yes, okay.